# Creating a mask using a binary image - matlab

Tags: matlab, overlay, mask

I need to overlay a binary mask (black and white image) over a gray-scale image where the white blobs are superimposed on the original image in black color.

Comment: Where are you having particular difficulty? Loading the image? Combining two images? Let us know what you have tried, what you expected and where you got stuck

Comment: image upload is not working as properly while using drag & drop tool. Pop-up box is coming up after asking to leave or stay on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what's the problem. Two possible solutions for this (unknown) problem may be:

```
img = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
bw = false(size(img));
bw(25:100,50:150) = 1;
res1 = imoverlay(img,bw,[1 1 1]);
res2 = img.*bw;
figure;
subplot(221);
imshow(img);
title('original');
subplot(222);
imshow(bw)
title('mask');
subplot(223);
imshow(res1);
title('res1');
subplot(224);
imshow(res2)
title('res2');
```

which outputs:
[image]

Comment: Not using Lena? :(